# How to get only one value from hashmap which contains key String, and list<Object>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

How to get only one value from hashmap which contains key String, and list

hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Person>> person = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Person>>();
```

constructor Person:

```
Person(int phone, String mail){
    this.phone = phone;
    this.mail = mail;
}
```

method to get object:

```
protected void findObject(String lname){
    if (person.containsKey(lname)) {
            System.out.println(lname + " phone: " + person.get(lname));
    }
}
```

but i need two methods:

```
protected void findPhone(String lname){
//should get only phone from Person;
}

protected void findMail(String mail){
//should get only mail from Person;
}
```

work like this:

```
protected List<Integer> findPhone(String lname) {
    List<Integer> listPhone = null;
    if (person.containsKey(lname)) {
        listPhone = person.get(lname).stream()
        .map(Person::getPhone)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
    return listPhone;
}

protected List<String> findMail(String lname) {
    List<String> listMail = null;
    if (person.containsKey(lname)) {
        listMail = person.get(lname).stream()
        .map(Person::getPhone)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
    return listmail;
}
```

Comment: any thing is possible if you know what your looking for

Comment: "*is it possible?*" - Last time I checked, Java was turing-complete, so it is possible. As to how... get the [`entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--), iterate over each `Entry`, get its associated `List<Person>`, iterate over this list, look for your person.

Comment: You `void` should probably be `Person`. Also, your `Map` should look like `Map<String, List<Person>> person = new HashMap();`

Comment: Also, according to your `Person` constructor, you will not be able to find a person by lname. You only set phone number and mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
protected void findPhone(String lname) {
    if (person.containsKey(lname)) {
        List<Integer> listPhone = person.get(lname).stream()
                .map(Person::getPhone)
                .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

and

```
protected void findMail(String lname) {
    if (person.containsKey(lname)) {
        List<String> listMails = person.get(lname).stream()
                .map(Person::getMail)
                .collect(toList());
    }
}
```